# Is music/dancing halal under this condition?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I know a guy who listens to music because he has a condition and music helps him control himself and it is so helpful for him. Under circumstances where music/dancing is good for you is it halal?

Comment: There's no consensus about Music being haram. Some scholars who say it is haram may consider making some conditions for allowing it under specific conditions. Usually conditions of this kinds would take at least two aspects into account: Would you die if you don't commit this "sin"? or is committing this "sin" much better than committing another one? ...

Comment: What about improvement of health

Comment: Improvement is a rather luxery issue. Conditions to relax verdicts are related to a necessity not to a convenience or improvement.

Comment: What if music acts as a cure for depression or other conditions that literally destroy the life or will of people. The music may act as a motivation, it can prevent the people from harming others maybe or harming themselves?

Comment: IMO discussing this is somewhat meaningless as there are trustworthy scholars saying music is permissible so why should we restrict all our considerations on those saying otherwise? The existence of an opposite view is a relaxation of a rule. As even if X says it is haram, the ruling is not absolut. AFAIK ibn Sina used as a first physician what is by now known as music therapy. Imam Malik wanted to become a singer before his mother lead him to hadith sciences the whole community of Medina considered music permissible. Music is located in a grey area of permission as there are haram parts of it

Comment: There may be trustworthy scholars who agree it is permissible but there are a lot more trustworthy scholars who agree that it isn’t and this has been the view for most people for years so it seems correct that music is haram I just wanted to know under what conditions it may be accepted.

Comment: In fact you may visit gigs and parties in Saudi Arabia (one of the imams of the haram said dance if you can dance sing if you can sing) and with the actual development we may expect go to after hajj and 'Umrah parties within the next five to ten years. والحمدلله على كل حال.

Answer (score 1):

While listening to a music, one can identify what emotions, feelings the music arouses. Then, based on this, one can make a judgement. Definitely, music has a motivating effect on people, but the extent and nature of how each individual is affected by the music or rhythm differs. There are certain types of music that must be stayed away, and scholars unanimously agree on these. Two of these are : voice of a female singer is *haram* for males. Also, music with tempting lyrics and video clips must be stayed away. Hence, unfortunately, most trending music and video clips on YouTube etc. are disqualified.

IMHO, had the music be a good alternative for physiological therapy, Islam would have opened the doors for it, and wouldn't let us be bothered with such questions. Metaphorically speaking, if we liken the human spirit to a cave, voice/sound would fill it pretty easily. The deceptive satisfaction felling that arouses after listening to (loud) music makes us believe that there is benefit in that, just because of the phenomenon in the metaphor. Nevertheless, *nafs* (soul) would seek for means to fill this cave, and satisfy itself. Related to this is a verse :

> *O you mountains! Sing you back the Praises of Allah (swt) with him! and you birds! (Quran 34:10)*

A tafseer of this verse says :

> These indicate that Almighty God gave to David’s (PBH) praises and glorifications such strength and a sound so loud and agreeable they brought the mountains to ecstasy, which, each like a huge gramophone or a man, formed a circle on the horizon around the chief reciter, reciting also the glorifications. Is this possible, I wonder? Is it the truth?
>
> Yes, it is the truth. Every mountain with caves can speak with man in man’s language like a parrot. By means of an echo. You say: “All praise be to God!” to the mountain before you, and the mountain will declare: “All praise be to God!”, exactly the same as you. Since Almighty God has given this ability to mountains, it can surely be made to develop, and that seed made to sprout. *(Risale-i Nur 20th Word)*

For me, the lesson to take is, word of Allah (swt), words that reminds Allah (swt) and their recitations are sufficient to satisfy this profound need of the human soul. Looking for examples? Check these :

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWnzLwEqxZk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb89Uc49iB4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlT4oqd4RTk

In addition to these, reciting names of Allah (swt) with one's inner voice and pondering on their meanings, and particular manifestations of these names in his/her personal life would fill a big gap in his/her soul.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Also what if music helps more because maybe language barriers or even if the person finds music a lot more soothing but becomes frightened or saddened by some of the verses in the Quran?

Comment: At the end of the day, I guess it is the type of the music that matters. In the long term, learning Arabic might be a perfect path to pursue. There are tons of online Arabic courses that especially focus of Quranic Arabic. I get frightened and feel sad due to some verses too. There are verses which tell about Hell. But these *define* from what one should strive to stay away. Had Allah (swt) told us about Hell the first time on the day of judgement, that would be both unjust and make us astonished. But He says that there is sth called as Hell and wants us to avoid it.

Comment: Some verses make us sad or frightened, and this is the same for Rasulullah (PBUH). Please check this *munajaat* http://www.duas.org/jkabeer1.htm . This is one of His wonderful *zikr*s, and every section ends with *Protect us from the Fire, O Lord.* or similar *dua*'s